# Deployment React/Node App in Heroku fails

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

1. I cant figure out whats wrong, please help!

   -----> Node.js app detected
      -----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
      NODE_VERBOSE=false
      NODE_ENV=production
      NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
      -----> Installing binaries
      engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
      engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 8.x...
      Downloading and installing node 8.11.4...
      Using default npm version: 5.6.0
      -----> Restoring cache
      Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):

   - node_modules
   - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
     -----> Building dependencies
     Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
     up to date in 5.321s
     -----> Caching build
     Clearing previous node cache
     Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
   - node_modules
   - bower_components (nothing to cache)
     -----> Pruning devDependencies
     Skipping because npm 5.6.0 sometimes fails when running 'npm prune' due to a known issue
     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19356

     You can silence this warning by updating to at least npm 5.7.1 in your package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version
     -----> Build succeeded!
     -----> Discovering process types
     Procfile declares types     -> (none)
     Default types for buildpack -> web
     -----> Compressing...
     Done: 33.9M
     -----> Launching...
     Released v36
     https://space-hangman.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "github-fetcher-fullstack-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "react-dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "start": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.15.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.8.6",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-simple-popover": "^0.2.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "unirest": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your repo url ?

Comment: https://github.com/begonaguereca/hangman :)

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping, I am getting `Error: Cannot find module './keys/config.js'`, you have added `config.js` to `.gitignores`

Answer (score 0):

You can run easily your project under heroku using `express.js`. Your all dependencies must be under `dependencies`

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "Add yours",
    "postinstall": "Same with build",
    "start": "node server.js" // Heroku looks for this
  },
  "dependencies": {
     Add all your dependencies here
  }
```

Create **server.js** file under root

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Your dist folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/react-client/dist/'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/react-client/dist/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**SynonymFinder.js**

```
.header("X-Mashape-Key", process.env.SYNONYMKEY) // You can use Environment Variables for API Key
```

Add your API Key to **Config Vars** under your **Heroku Project Settings** Page

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your Node and npm versions in `engines` as an object;

package.json:

```
{
"name": "github-fetcher-fullstack-v2", 
  ...

//starts here 

 "engines": {    
    "node": "10.x"  
    "npm": ""       
  }

 //ends here
```

and you might also need a server if your site is static, check out [this link](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)